# RSSI value in gamekit iPhone API

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, gamekit

Is it possible to get bluetooth RSSI (Radio signal strength) value in gamekit iPhone API?
If it is possible, can I have some sample code?

If it is not possible is there any other way to get bluetooth RSSI value in iPhone OS 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no supported way to find out any of the data about any of the radios (cellular, wifi, or bluetooth). If you have need of such a feature you should [file](http://bugreporter.apple.com/) a bug report.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I am trying to develop a bluetooth application in which i need to know the bluetooth signal strength that signal is weak or it is full. Is there any way to calculate signal strength ??

Comment: No, like I said above, there is no radio access, you either know you have a GameKit connection or not. There is no granularity. Likewise, the ExternalAccessory interface does not expose any radio level interfaces.

Comment: is it possible to get RSSI value in MAC OS ??