# Bluetooth strength indicator iPhone

Tags: ios4, bluetooth

I have been looking at the GameKit for a while and have not found anything so I figured I would ask this here. Is there a function you could call or anything that would return either an int or a string saying how strong the bluetooth signal is? For instance "10" or "low" for low strength, "50" or "medium" for medium strength etc.

Comment: This question was already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164136/rssi-value-in-gamekit-iphone-api

Comment: @garzanti acctually you can do it , get the Wifi signal strength but you have to use Private API's(more exactly apple80211.framework). but it will never be accepted in the app store

Comment: @Radu Maybe you can, but when you make real products, you use only the official APIs assumed by the vendor. So this is the case that should be followed. What Muller can do is to study if he has access to the HCI on iOS, if he has he could speak directly with the BT chip and ask the RSSI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do the same thing with Wifi about 2 months ago and the only way to do it is to access iOS's private API's.

Sow if Bluetooth API is like WiFi API the only way it is to access private APIs which is a breach in the Apple contract and it will never be accepted on the Apple store.

- using standard libraries - best you can do is detect a WiFi - Bluetooth connection;
- using private API's      - YES but documentation on these API's are very hard to come by!

This might not be the answer you are looking for, but it's the best I got.

Comment: can you tell, what private API you have used in the WiFi case?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions the library is Apple80211 you have the documentation at the link above link.